# LyX Local layout for a custom environment

Tags: lyx-layouts

I have the following local layout in LyX.

```
Format 66
Preamble
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \newcounter{YourTurn}
  \newenvironment{YourTurn}[1][]{\refstepcounter{YourTurn}\par\medskip
  \noindent \color{green}\textbf{Your Turn ~\theYourTurn. #1} \rmfamily\color{black}}{\medskip}
EndPreamble

Counter YourTurn
 LabelString          "\arabic{YourTurn}"
End

Style YourTurn
    LeftMargin            "   MMMMMM"
    LaTeXName YourTurn
  ParSkip       0.4
  Align     Left
  LabelFont
      Family              Roman
      Series              Medium
      Size                Normal
      Color               Magenta
  EndFont
  LaTeXType Item_Environment
  LabelType Static
  LabelCounter YourTurn
  ItemCommand YourTurn
  LabelString "Your Turn \theYourTurn. "
End
```

My MWE code in LyX looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,english]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcounter{YourTurn}
\newenvironment{YourTurn}[1][]{\refstepcounter{YourTurn}\par\medskip
     \noindent \color{green}\textbf{Your Turn ~\theYourTurn. #1} 
     \rmfamily\color{black}}{\medskip}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{YourTurn}
   \YourTurn This should be Your Turn 1
   \YourTurn This should be Your Turn 2
  \end{YourTurn}

Standard text 1

Standard Text 2
  \begin{YourTurn}
   \YourTurn This should be Your Turn 3
  \end{YourTurn}

\end{document}
```

The LyX screenshot looks like this:

[image]

While the output looks like this:

[image]

I am unsure why there are YourTurn environments inserted where I am not expecting them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post a complete  a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), not a chunk of not working lyx code that show some like a list setting but omit the text that you show in the screenshots. Better if the  MWE is exported to LaTeX.  Probably even most LyX users  cannot understand the LyX code without running it in the LyX GUI, but read without problems the LaTeX export.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot the MWE (It is LyX that has been converted to LateX)